# ERR: Node-gyp - Gitlab Pipeline suddenly not working without any changes

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, node-gyp

I was working on a project and pushed it to organizations gitlab instance. Then the pipeline failed. So I was investigating where the error comes from and had to determine, that it were not my changes because of the following.

I reran a pipeline (which ran successfully in the past) from an older commit and it failed also. The same error as I have now.

So in my point of view this tells that my changes haven't messed anything up.

Our gitlab runners are on a kubernetes cluster and the pipeline works with a docker image (node:16-alpine).

*.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
stages:
  - cli_build_and_analyze
  - some other stages

job_build_and_analyze:
  stage: cli_build_and_analyze
  image: artifacts.company.com/docker-mirror/node:16-alpine
  tags:
    - linux-k8s
  script:
    - export http_proxy="http://proxy.company.com:8080"
    - export https_proxy="http://proxy.company.com:8080"
    - export no_proxy=".company.com"
    - node --version
    - cd cli
    - npm config set registry https://artifacts.company.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-mirror/
    - npm install
    - npx pkg-fetch -n node16 -p win -a x64
    - yarn build
    - yarn coverage
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - cli/*
    expire_in: 4 h

some other stages: ...
```

*error*

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.5.0 (f0a95a76)
  on server-k8s 9-Y7h2DK
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
00:00
Using Kubernetes namespace: opcerver
Using Kubernetes executor with image artifacts.company.com/docker-mirror/node:16-alpine ...
Using attach strategy to execute scripts...
Preparing environment
00:03
Waiting for pod server/runner-9-y7h2dk-project-1654-concurrent-0bck9f to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotInitialized: "containers with incomplete status: [init-permissions]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
Running on runner-9-y7h2dk-project-1653-concurrent-0bck9f via gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-6965989c6b-b6l9x...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/teams/teamname/validation-tool/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 920d7008 as accept-regex...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
01:13
$ export http_proxy="http://proxy.company.com:8080"
$ export https_proxy="http://proxy.company.com:8080"
$ export no_proxy=".company.com"
$ node --version
v16.15.0
$ cd cli
$ npm config set registry https://artifacts.company.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-mirror/
$ npm install
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /builds/teams/team/validation-tool/cli/node_modules/bufferutil
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:330:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:159:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:202:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:294:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:418:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.12.14-122.106-default
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /builds/teams/team/validation-tool/cli/node_modules/bufferutil
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-07-06T11_27_26_562Z-debug-0.log
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Maybe it's helpful to have the dependencies because of the node-gyp error:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
},
"dependencies": {
    "commander": "^8.3.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.11",
    "node-opcua": "^2.62.7",
    "pkg": "^5.5.1"
}
```

I removed the '^' of every version to ensure it's the exact same and still the same error. (Also tried it with newer node version and other docker images.)

How I said it once worked and in the last three weeks something has changed but I don't know what.

I'm searching for a solution since four days so every idea is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention: Of course I could just install python (then there appears another error, and if fixed again one). But I'm interested in the reason why it suddenly fails (Root Cause Analysis - clean code dev...)

Answer (score 0):

Alright figured it out by myself.

Something must be messed up in our mirror. If I took the origin node:16-alpine it worked!

nvm... :)